# Is complexity O(kM(n)) polynomial complexity?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

Definition :

**O(kM(n))** :  - computational complexity of [modular exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation)

where **k** is number of exponent bits , **n** is number of digits , and **M(n)** is computational complexity of the [Newton's division algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

How can I determine is this computational complexity polynomial complexity ?

In fact notation **M(n)** is that what confusing me most .

Comment: Agreed that the notation is confusing.  Personally I hate when people say "the function f(n)" when they really mean "the function f".  I cringe whenever I see "O(f(n))" when what is really meant is "O(f)".  I know it's convention, but.... :)

Comment: Some times complexity is multivariate and then you want to know which variables you apply the functions to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about the division algorithm.

- Does the division algorithm have complexity O(n)?  If so, then modular exponentiation is O(k n).
- Does the division algorithm have complexity O(n^c) for some constant c?  If so, then modular exponentiation is O(k n^c).
- Does the division algorithm have complexity O(log n)?  If so, then modular exponentiation is O(k log n).

Etc.

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of modular exponentiation is polynomial in the length of the exponent and the length of the modulus even with regular long division, so it is also polynomial with a faster division algorithm. M(n) is the complexity of multiplying two n-digit/bit numbers together ([see here](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/personal/pborwein/PAPERS/P29.pdf)).